# how to use LaTeX grid-system package in r markdown (and put r chunks within LaTeX environments)?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, grid-system

I am trying to use the LaTeX [grid-system](https://github.com/bitzl/latex-grid-system) package in r markdown. Does anyone know how to do that? When making cells including plain texts all goes well, but when trying to include an r chunk I get this error:

````
output file: testtest.knit.md

    ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
\gridsystem@cellcontent0 ...(cars) ``` \par ``` ##
                                                  ## speed dist #### Min. : ...
l.106 \end{Row}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS testtest.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output testtest.pdf --template "C:\Users\pc\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
Execution halted
````

I used this code:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{grid-system}
---

\begin{Row}%
    \begin{Cell}{2}
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
    \end{Cell}
    \begin{Cell}{1}
    Some text using 1/3 of the width.
    \end{Cell}
\end{Row}
````

*update:*

The solution `comment=">"` as mentioned in the comments works for the code above, but when trying to include a plot, like this:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{grid-system}
---


\begin{Row}
    \begin{Cell}{5}
```{r, comment='>'}
plot(pressure)
```
    \end{Cell}
    \begin{Cell}{1}
    Some text using 1/6 of the width.
    \end{Cell}
\end{Row}
````

it produces this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.98 \end{Row}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to avoid the hashes. Try using another character for comments by using `comment = '>'` for your chunk.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not sure if I understand what you mean. As a chunk option?

Comment: `{r cars, comment='>'}` . Or you set it globally (for all chunks) by calling `opts_chunk$set(comment='>')`

Comment: it works! thanks again. If you give this as an answer I will accept it. If I replace `summary(cars)` with `plot(pressure` I still got an error. Any ideas about a solution for that one too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of symbols, that have a special meaning in Tex. The hash is used in relation to create macros. Therefore LaTex is confused when you use a hash without escaping it. 
Setting the chunk option `comment` to another symbol like `>` or no symbol at all (`''`) will change this.

Concerning your second problem I am not sure why the translation of the code to include the plot in the final pdf fails. A work-around would be to generate the plot and directly use a LaTeX call to include the file:

````
```{r cars, engine='R', echo = F, include=F, fig.path='plots/'}
plot(pressure, col = 'blue', pch = 16)
```
\includegraphics{plots/cars-1.pdf}
````

You can control the name of the folder with `fig.path`. The plots are named using the chunk name.